# Como obtener el valuemember de combobox dentro de un datagridview

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy haciendo un pequeño programa, pero me surgió la siguiente duda, ¿Cómo puedo obtener el **ValueMember** que esta dentro de un **DataGridView** como se muestra en la siguiente imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La lista que se muestra la cargo de la siguiente manera:

```
private void cagarProductos()
{
  try
  {
      productosBindingSource.DataSource = bissP.getAll2();
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
      MessageBox.Show("No se pudo cargar la lita de productos.", "Sistema", 
                       MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
  }
}
```

El combo lo lleno mediante un bindingsource.